# highlight the selected tab

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on angularJs and bootstrap application.
Currently working on creating a tabs using angularJS, i want to highlight the selected tab so that users can easily recognize that the tab highlighted is selected. **Please suggest how to highlight the selected tab with color** #FBDFD9.

Please find the exisiting working code to display tabs : http://plnkr.co/edit/CAlrAzHO2THuglQrsTIi?p=preview

sample html code:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsParentController">
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
             heading="{{workspace.name}}"
             active=workspace.active>
            <div ng-controller="TabsChildController">
                <div>
                    {{$parent.workspace.id}} : {{ $parent.workspace.name}}
                </div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="workspace.name"/>
            </div>     
        </tab>
        <tab select="addWorkspace()">
            <tab-heading>
                <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
            </tab-heading>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

--EDIT--

Please suggest how to show the outline of the tabs. If there are many tabs, its appearing just like a text without any outline indicating that as a tab. If noticed the output in http://plnkr.co/edit/CAlrAzHO2THuglQrsTIi?p=preview , outline of the tab is shown only for the selected tab. Please advice how to show the outlines of all the tabs(active tab and inactive tabs). I tried to find the solution but could not find the appropriate ID or classname of the tab to write the **css** code to show the outer line of the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the HTML with Chrome to see which CSS selector is being used in Bootstrap to style active tabs. Modify your CSS to add this rule:

```
.nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
  background-color: #FBDFD9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap adds `active` class to the active tab, so just target it in your css:

```
.nav-tabs>.active>a {
  background-color: #FBDFD9;
}
```

Since the specificity of the selector `.nav-tabs>.active>a` is the same as the specificity of bootstrap's selector, to have your styles override either use `!important`

```
.nav-tabs>.active>a {
  background-color: #FBDFD9; !important;
}
```

or place your custom styles after bootstrap's in `index.html`:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

Here is [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpH3KLwRvNjXGDuHBY9M?p=preview).